# Create a file or report or excel thread in mvc3 dotnet c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, excel

I'm using mvc3 and although I see this question a lot I am yet to find a definitive answer as to which technology to use. Most of the solutions seem to contradict each other, use a mish mash of old and new libraries. There seems to be a lot of talk about async but then many answers appear as to why it isn't 'safe'.

What is required is.

1. MVC3 website - User clicks button to create a report.
2. The report is large and will be created and stored on the web server disk 
   (may take up to 10 minuets).
3. The user does not need to know when the report has finished being created.
4. The web page just returns the fact that the report is being created and lets you
   continue without interacting with that process again.
5. For the sake of argument the server hardware is pretty decent but the may be over 100
   concurrent users who all create their own separate big report at exactly the same time.
   I would like the only issue it could create is that the server hardware inst powerful 
   enough rather than it being a config or software issue.

I have been looking at the 'Task Parallel Library' as maybe the means to do this. But again I'm getting many different reports of how to do this.

Some people suggest a WCF service but again many conflicting reports as to why / why not to do it this way. i.e Now out of date / better alternatives etc

Generally speaking what I want is to create the file in another thread that isn't going to mess up iis (running out of threads from pools or such like depending on the method used)

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty open ended set of questions.  That's not a bad thing, but there aren't many "right" direct answers to them.  But there are some things to watch out for.  Some choices depend on your reliability requirements, etc.

For instance, you want a method that isn't going "to mess up iis", referring to starving the thread pool that is serving requests.  To do this, you need to do your work on a thread outside of the thread pool.  You can do this in any way you see fit, depending on your requirements and measured performance characteristics.  The two options for you are:

- Start a new thread in some way - task parallel library (TPL), new Thread, or other.
- Host the report generation in a separate process (e.g. a Windows service).

There is also a third option to use async support built into your framework of choice.  For MVC you have async controllers.  I don't list this as an option for you because you said you don't want to wait for the report to complete before sending the response.  Async controllers/pages will buy you nothing here and would in fact hurt.

You also have to think of the other side with respect to reliability: yes, you don't want to mess up iis, but do you also care about iis messing up you?  Your web process can be recycled, or if it goes down for any other reason, your report generation will die as well.  If this is important to you, then you must have a recovery mechanism in place or host out of process so you have separate control over reliability of the service.

Another benefit of hosting out-of-process is you could physically deploy that process on a separate server from the front-end application.  You could then optimize to use the thread pool from that application without having anything to do with the front-end.  It would also reduce context switching if you've got a lot going on at once.  Additionally, you could scale out the report generation process separately if need be.  Finally, you could separately deal with permissions and other issues with automating excel, etc. if that is the path you're going down.

The downside of out-of-process is added complexity.  You'll need some communication between the two, maybe WCF one-way calls, maybe a message bus, whatever works for your requirements.  You need to weigh this cost against your needs and the value you expect from reliability/scalability/etc.

Now, for your tool of choice for doing async work, it's largely up to you.  In my opinion, the TPL is a pretty good abstraction over async work, and the default task scheduler for running your tasks is very smart about thread usage so you largely don't have to think much about it.  Also, .NET 4.5 is shipping with built-in compiler support to make working with the TPL much simpler than it is even today and seem more like synchronous style (search for async/await or maybe start [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for an example.)

Bottom line is, I wouldn't get too uptight or paralyzed about which technology stack to use in general.  List your nonfunctional requirements - performance, scalability, reliability, etc. - figure out which combinations fit your requirements, and choose one.  If you're worried about making the wrong choice, try to architect the solution in a way that allows you to deal with change in this area efficiently.  You can always measure and change later if need be.

Comment: A very good response but not really want I was after. I pretty much know the implications of threading I suppose what I was really asking is the best current practice and what most of you are using. I don't really want to learn another system of doing this if next year ms have decided to replace it with .......